# Check state of UI switch in a table cell using Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am using Xamarin to develop an IOS app. I Have defined my table view and have UISwitch for each cell's AccessoryVenterView
I need to interate all cells and display cell data for those cells where its switch is ON

```
var indexPaths = table.IndexPathsForVisibleRows;
                foreach (var indexPath in indexPaths) 
                {
                    var cell = table.CellAt (indexPath);
                    if (/*cell.AccessoryView.isOn*/)
                    {

                        new UIAlertView ("On", "This cell has its switch on and its value is "/*+CELL_DATA*/, null, "OK", null).Show();
                    }
                }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if your AccessoryView is of type UISwitch.

```
var indexPaths = table.IndexPathsForVisibleRows;
foreach (var indexPath in indexPaths) 
{
    var cell = table.CellAt (indexPath);
    var switchView = cell.AccessoryView as UISwitch;

    if(switchView == null)
       continue;

    if (switchView.On)
    {
        // if it is a default cell you get the text like this
        var cellText = cell.TextLabel.Text;

        new UIAlertView ("On", "This cell has its switch on and its value is " + cellText, null, "OK", null).Show();
    }
}
```

This works for default cells. If you use custom cells you need to cast the cell to the type of your cell. So `var cell = table.CellAt (indexPath);` becomes `var cell = (MyCustomCell)table.CellAt (indexPath);`. Then you are able to access the properties of your custom cell.

Also notice that UIAlertView is depricated and should be replaced with AlertViewController.